# Change "Exif" data between onPictureTaken and write()?

Tags: android, camera, exif

I am developing an app for a *custom* android device. It is still early in the development and it is possible that the camera may physically be rotated 90 degrees to the rest of the device. This means that there is scope for great confusion between portrait and landscape for any images it takes. For this reason I would like absolute control over the Exif data in any images that the camera takes. The portrait vs landscape information in the camera parameters may be incorrect. For this reason I would like to be able to force a change in the Exif data inside onPictureTaken, before the image is saved. Is this possible, and if so how?

I am struggling because examples of playing with exif data seem to either work by changing camera parameters, or by working on an already saved file - so that's either too early or too late!

```
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] jpg_data, Camera camera)
    {
        // can I change exif data here?

        try 
        {       
            FileOutputStream buf = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            buf.write(jpg_data);
            //... etc.
```

**EDIT:** Maybe I am misunderstanding something here... is there Exif data already contained within the jpg_data that gets passed to onPictureTaken? Or is it optionally added?

Comment: That is exactly the right place to change `data`. How many exif classes did you try?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not even sure what you mean by "exif classes". There appears to be a class called "exifinterface", but that appears to need a *file* in order to construct, so I presume its a set of methods that operate on the file once its already been created.

Comment: So you only tried ExifInterface. You did not try other classes. Are there other classes?

Comment: Yes, Exif data is already contained within the jpg_data that gets passed to onPictureTaken

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of writing exif data in Android is by using the ExifInterface which sadly only works on files that have already been written to disk.

If you wish to do the exif write without using a library, then you would have to do it after your `FileOutputStream` is finished writing the file.

If you don't mind using a library, Sanselan (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) might have the ability to do it to a byte[] array, but the documentation is pretty limited.