# How to add extra String information to a bitmap or image in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I want to add some extra string information to my image file, so that I can extract it anytime I want again. I want to add location where this image was captured, so that I can extract later, where this was captured.
If I store this info to DB, clearing the data will cause me to lose the information, so I want to know if there is a way to store the info with image only.

Comment: There's nowhere you can store it which will keep the data after clearing it, that would remove the point of clearing data. is that the only issue with storing it in the DB? as thats the best solution that you have. You could extend Bitmap and include a 'location' field which you save to the db.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you wanting to do is edit the EXIF header values contained in the photo - this is described at [Change "Exif" data between onPictureTaken and write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610784/change-exif-data-between-onpicturetaken-and-write)